# PDF.js not showing PDF files in correct page order

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I'm using the following code to display PDF in IE browser using PDF.js. But the pages are not showing up in same order as the original file.How do I fix this?
This happens when for large PDF documents alone...

```
if (response && response.data.Success) {
            var arrayBufferedPdf = base64ToArrayBuffer(response.data.Document);
            PDFJS.workerSrc = "./scripts/pdf.worker.js";
            PDFJS.getDocument({ data: arrayBufferedPdf }).then(function (pdf) {
                var pageNum = 1;
                var numPages = pdf.numPages;
                for (pageNum; pageNum <= numPages; pageNum++) {
                    pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(function (page) {
                        var scale = 1.25;
                        var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);
                        var canvasContainer = document.getElementById('canvas_container');
                        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                        canvas.height = viewport.height;
                        canvas.width = viewport.width;
                        canvasContainer.appendChild(canvas);
                        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                        page.render({ canvasContext: context, viewport: viewport });
                    });
                }
             });
        }
```

Comment: `pdf.getPage(pageNum).then(...)` sounds like this getter was an asynchronous method?

Comment: yes.. It is.. PDFwill be convert to base 64 and given as response..

Comment: Well then you will most likely have to “collect” the results of all those `getPage` calls first, so that you can render them in the right order afterwards ...

Comment: This works fine for documents less than 20 pages but more than that... we are getting pages in incorrect order

Comment: @Jackphilip Whether you were able to fix it? for particular pdf it is breaking for me.I am not sure whether it is pdf issue or pdfjs.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. I fixed the same using async and await. please check.

```
async function renderPages(pdfDoc) {
                    var docId = pdf.docId;
                    var pdfDocumentObject =  {};
                    pdfDocumentObject[docId] = pdfDoc;
                    pdfData.setPdfDocumentObject(pdfDocumentObject);
                    for (var num = 1; num <= pdfDoc.numPages; num++) {
                        await pdfDoc.getPage(num).then(renderPage);
                    }
                }

                if(pdf.docBlob && pdf.docId == null){
                    var blob = b64toBlob(pdf.docBlob, 'pdf');
                    pdfurl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                    PDFJS.getDocument(pdfurl).then(renderPages);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for answer in 2022:

If you are retrieving an entire document, and using loops to retrieve the pages one-by-one with the loop index or a counter, you know sometimes it doesn't render the pages in order. To fix this, **instead of using loops, use a recursive function instead to get each page** - that is:

*pseudocode in javascript* - $ denoting variable

instead of:

```
loop $index:
    downloadedPDF.getPage($index).then(...);
```

use:

```
$counter = 1; /*denoting page 1*/

function getSinglePage(){
    downloadedPDF.getPage($counter).then(()=>{
        $counter++;
        getSinglePage();
    })
}
```

then trigger the function once to start the recursion

```
getSinglePage($counter);
```

Comment: I was able to implement this solution  in 2023 and it definitely addressed the issues I was having with PDF pages being rendered asynchronously out of order.